# chrome.tabs.executeScript not working?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn to use the chrome.tabs.executeScript commend. I've created a simple extension with a browser action. My background.html file currently looks like this:

```html
<html>
<script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The "content_script.js" file contains document.body.bgColor='red'.

When pushing the browser action's button nothing happens. Obviously I'm missing something very basic.

I've checked with console.log that indeed control reaches the chrome.tabs.executeScript calls when the browser action is pressed. Otherwise I'm not sure how to even check if my content script's code is run (it seems not; console.log I put in the content script has no effect, but maybe it shouldn't have one even if the script is run successfully).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure you have domain and tab permissions in the manifest:

```js
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
]
```

Then to change body color try:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"});
```

Also keep in mind that content scripts are not injected into any `chrome://` or extension gallery pages.

Comment: The key problem for me was that upon booting a new tab in a new window the default url is chrome://newtab which prohibits content scripts as mentioned above. Going to any other url as a starting point worked just fine.

Comment: this doesn't actually load the script from the file, however. it executes the code in the raw.

Comment: FYI, you can use `*://*/*` instead of `http://*/*` and `https://*/*` to set permissions for all urls

Comment: KyleMit I think '*' will make it also match ftp etc which is prob not what you want

Comment: It's not recommended to set those permission just for `executeScript` (for more details see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59270306/5267751))

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to have the extension available on `chrome://` with the following flag chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls ? Doesn't seem to work for me though, even after adding it to `permissions`

Answer (score 14):

For those of you still having issues, you need to make sure to reload the extension's permissions in Chrome.

Go to `chrome://extensions` , scroll to your extension, and click on "reload". Make sure that your permissions have been updated by clicking on the permissions link right next to your extension.

Comment: I don't see any permissions link in my extensions page.

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't need and don't want the 'tabs' permission for `executeScript`.

```json
"permissions": [
  "http://*/*", 
  "https://*/*"
]
```

Should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

It's not recommended to use `http://*/*` and `https://*/*`. From the [Google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/):

> To inject a programmatic content script, provide the [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission in the manifest. This grants secure access to the active site's host and temporary access to the tabs permission, enabling the content script to run on the current active tab without specifying [cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission).

Instead, (as suggested in the page) just use `activeTab` permission.

---

Remark: more explanation for the security issue

> Without `activeTab`, this extension would need to request full, persistent access to every web site, just so that it could do its work if it happened to be called upon by the user. This is a lot of power to entrust to such a simple extension. And *if the extension is ever compromised, the attacker gets access to everything the extension had.*
>
> In contrast, an extension with the `activeTab` permission only obtains access to a tab in response to an explicit user gesture. If the extension is compromised the attacker would need to wait for the user to invoke the extension before obtaining access. And that access only lasts until the tab is navigated or is closed.

(emphasis mine)

In the example code posted by the OP, `activeTab` is sufficient.

However, if the extension is more complex and needs to work "automatically" (i.e. without the user clicking the button); then *this method will not work* and additional permission is required.

Comment: Yep, but "when the user invokes the extension - for example by clicking its action". Therefore extension scripts will not be injected in page until user clicks it's icon or select context menu entry - which kind of breaks concept for a lot of extensions out there

Comment: @emvaized Addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers above seems to be working fine for manifest version 2 but when it comes manifest-3 their seems to be some workaround to make the content-script load in the latest manifest 3.We need to use the following steps to execute content script in manifest 3

First adding permission "scripting" in manifest

```
"permissions": [
"storage",
"tabs",
"activeTab",
"scripting"
```

]

Once the scripting perimission is provided, we can use the [scripting api](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) like below

In background.js,

```
 chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabList) => {
    if (!tabList.length) return;
    tabList.forEach((tab) => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
          files: ['contentScript.js'],
          target: {
            tabId: tab.id,
            allFrames: true
          }
        }
      );
   });
});
```

In the above code we are executing the contentScript for all the available tabs in tab browser.