# executeScript not executing in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The "executeScript" event is not working for me in my google chrome extension.
Here's the code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,tab){
    alert("!");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "alert('hello');"} );
  }
);
```

There are few problems, first and foremost is that the alert ("!") is fired 2 times on a tab refresh.
Second problem is that the "executeScript" is not doing anything.

Comment: Try adding your executescript code in a file and add it in there. Also don't forget to add permissions and don't use inline javascripts. `.onUpdated` does fire more than once as you have described. Else tell exactly what error do you get in `console`.

Comment: Nope, not working with an external file either.

Comment: Do you get any errors in `console`?

Comment: Problem was with permissions, a stackoverflow question helped:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996194/chrome-tabs-executescript-not-working

Comment: I told you `do not forget permission` :P If you don't observe any errors then probably permissions are the problem.

Comment: Please add an answer to your own question mentioning the correct permission settings for future research

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Instead of giving the extension this permission:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
```

I needed to give it the permissions like this:

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
```