# How call a function present in a extern .js file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This my question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996194/chrome-tabs-executescript-not-working), but the answer over there don't was clear for me.

So, come here know more about this subject.

I have a extern .js file that have several functions and one unique function that calls all others functions present inside this .js extern file.

Then, I need call this "Master Function" in my `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener` event.

Until now, all that I have you can see below, but nothing works.

***manifest.json***

```
 {
   "description": "Media Player for Flash",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Media Player",  
   "icons": {
    "128" : "picture/flash128.png" ,
    "48" : "picture/flash48.png" 
},
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>", "webNavigation", "webRequest", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

***callback.js***

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function onWindowLoad() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
      file: "externalfile.js"
    }, function() {});
  }, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["main_frame"]
  }, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

***externalfile.js***

```
function warning_A() {
  alert("warningA");
}

function warning_B() {
  alert("warningB");
}

function warning_C() {
  alert("warningC");
}

///////////////// CALLING ALL TREE PREVIOUS FUNCTIONS//////////////////////////////
function general_warning() {
  warning_A();
  warning_B();
  warning_C();
}
```

***PS:*** I'm loading my unpacked extension from localhost as test and using Google Chrome Version: 50.

Comment: `but nothing works.` is not very descriptive. What do you expect that should happen? Is there any error shown in the console? You don't do any attempt to call `general_warning` in your `onCompleted.addListener` callback.

Comment: Could you please rename your files so that they aren't misnamed? A "popup" has nothing to do with background pages. Use [the first notation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages#manifest) as you don't need that HTML and please rename your files as appropriate.

Comment: @t.niese, this is the main goal (call `general_warning()`) in my `onCompleted.addListener` callback. In others words, I want capture `general_warnings()` inside of `onCompleted.addListener`. Already tried several ways, but without sucess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to explicitly call `general_warning` in your `externalfile.js`.

```
function warning_A() {
  alert("warningA");
}

function warning_B() {
  alert("warningB");
}

function warning_C() {
  alert("warningC");
}

///////////////// CALLING ALL TREE PREVIOUS FUNCTIONS//////////////////////////////
function general_warning() {
  warning_A();
  warning_B();
  warning_C();
}

general_warning();
```