# Chrome.tabs.executeScript - tabs are not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension that has a button called 'btn3'. When I click on that button in the chrome extension (popup.html), it will click a button on the webpage. The button on the webpage has the following id: "regular-secondary-button send-message"

2 questions:

1. I get the error of "tabs are not defined" for chrome.tabs.executeScript in the following codes. How can I fix that?
2. Did I write anything wrong in the content_scripts.js?

Thanks!

**Script of the button in chrome extension window**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    document.getElementById('btn3').addEventListener('click', sendInMail)
});

sendInMail = function(){


    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0], {file: "content_script.js"});

}
```

**content_scripts.js**

```
alert("content_script is working!");

function clickSendInMailButton() {
    var SendInMailButton = document.getElementsByClassName("regular-secondary-button send-message"),

    SendInMailButton.click();
}

clickSendInMailButton();
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "LinkedIn Assistant",
  "description": "This extension makes a LSS AE successful.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
   "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  },

    "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ]


}
```

Comment: Aside from adding tab permissions in the manifest, please also make sure to reload the extension's permissions in the Chrome as suggested in this SO post - [chrome.tabs.executeScript not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996194/chrome-tabs-executescript-not-working).

Answer (score 8):

> the error of "tabs are not defined"

tabs[0] - you need to find it. Your script is executed in the context of popup.html. I hope popup.html contain

```
<head>
...
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
```

and

> **Script of the button in chrome extension window**

is from popup.js. And you never try to run code inside popup.html.

So, in this context no one knows about `tabs[0]`. You need to ask chrome which window and which tab is active now. It can be as ShwetaM wrote, or like this [from samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples,)

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id }, function (activeTabs) {
        activeTabs.map(function (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'content_script.js', allFrames: false });
        });
    });
});
```

or you can try without the `tab.id,`

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'content_script.js', allFrames: false });
```

because in this case the script will run in [the active tab of the current window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

When you specify in Manifest.json the `"content_scripts":` script will be executed when you create a tab and [every refresh](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-google-chrome-extensions--net-33076). I'm not sure, but maybe before loading the DOM. However, you should not specify the `"content_scripts":` in Manifest.json, because [this content script's code will be always injected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration,)

Also you must be sure that the active tab contains a button that you are looking for. Use `console.dir` for some object, especially arguments in a function; `console.log` for some text; `debugger` for happy debugging.

Comment: The getting [started guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) is misleading. The example uses a popup and makes reference to `tabs`, it actually does not work out of the box. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

you can just remove the parameter "tabs[0]"

> integer(optional)  tabId
>   The ID of the tab in which to run the script; defaults to the active tab of the current window.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sendInMail = function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({
                active: true,
                currentWindow: true
            }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0], {file: "content_script.js"});

  });
```

}

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I get this:
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in response to tabs.query: Error: Invocation of form tabs.executeScript(object, object) doesn't match definition tabs.executeScript(optional integer tabId, object details, optional function callback)...

Comment: ...
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://bdndljnkfidkacoflhfhpgilegpfgdja/sendInMail.js:10:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.sendInMail (chrome-extension://bdndljnkfidkacoflhfhpgilegpfgdja/sendInMail.js:6:15)

Comment: call this function from background js

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShwetaMatkar actually your suggestion worked for me.
I need to call this in the background.js and my script gets executed.