# Uncaught TypeError in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting the following error in my chrome extension:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined     at     HTMLButtonElement.changeColor.onclick (color.js:10)
```

I have a `background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    color: '#3aa757'
  }, function() {
    console.log("The color is green.");
  });
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: {
          hostEquals: 'www.amazon.in'
        },
      })],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});
```

And a `color.js` file:

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');
tabs = new Array();
chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data) {
  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = data.color;
  changeColor.setAttribute('value', data.color);
});
window.onload = function() {
  changeColor.onclick = function(element) {
    let color = element.target.value;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tabs[0].id, {
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "' + color + '";'
      });
  }
};
```

`index.html` file:

```
<button id="changeColor"></button>
<script src="color.js"></script>
```

`options.html` file:

```
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

`options.js` file:

```
const kButtonColors = ['#3aa757', '#e8453c', '#f9bb2d', '#4688f1']
function constructOptions(kButtonColors) {
  for (let item of kButtonColors) {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.style.backgroundColor = item;
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({
        color: item
      }, function() {
        console.log('color is ' + item);
      })
    });
    page.appendChild(button);
  }
}
constructOptions(kButtonColors);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  You might want to review [ask] for tips on forming a clear question-- doing so helps guarantee helpful, high-quality answers.  The post above currently doesn't seem to pose any question, nor contain the error text-- I think you need to remedy those issues to get good feedback from the community.

Comment: What error is showing up?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.changeColor.onclick (color.js:10)

Comment: Uhm............. Your `tabs` array is empty: `tabs = new Array()` - it doesn't have an element at `0` index, which is why the error is displayed.

Comment: remove the parameter "tabs.[0]". the same problem with
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694611/chrome-tabs-executescript-tabs-are-not-defined/49755341#49755341)

Answer (score 0):

in `options.js` add

```
  let page = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');
```

the files you download from the tutorial website are not up-to-date

use the snippets from the tutorial, not the downloaded files.