# Chrome's tabs.executeScript - Not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im writing a chrome extension which will create a new tab with a URL(ds_url) and perform some operations for getting the DOM elements information.

Below is the code in the background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url:ds_url, active:true}, function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "caseDoubleClickScript.js", allFrames: true, runAt: "document_end"}, function(results){ 
        });
    });  
});
```

Below is My Manifest code:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "RMQA Rules",
"description": "This extension reads the cases and grabs data to perform some automation",
"version": "1.1.1",
"icons": { 
    "16": "icon16x16.png",
    "48": "icon48x48.jpeg",
    "128": "icon128x128.png" 
        },
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon128x128.png",
    "default_title": "Click To Start the Automation",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
                },
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "jquery-2.2.2.min.js", "background.js"]
            },
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "css": ["main.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-2.2.2.min.js", "contentScript.js",     "casePageContentScript.js", "caseDoubleClickScript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ],
"web_accessible_resources": ["casePageContentScript.js","caseDoubleClickScript.js"],
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "webNavigation",
    "https://www.example.com/*"
            ],
"web_accessible_resources": [ "success.png" ]
}
```

But I'm not able to read the DOM elements in the newly created URL from the `caseDoubleClickScript.js` file.

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console? This related SO post - [chrome.tabs.executeScript not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996194/chrome-tabs-executescript-not-working) might help.

Comment: Thanks Teyam, The issue is fixed now. I have updated the '"matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"]' as '"matches": ["http://*/*"]'.